# Execute External function belonging to other process

Tags: c++, windows, process, ipc

I would need help with a problem. I have 2 processes running, one the Watchdog and the other a simple test process. I need process 2 to call code from the Watchdog, the reason I do this is to reduce the size of process 2. For example process 2 must call a function called "IsSafe" from the watchdog. The IsSafe function relies on other code belonging to Watchdog process and it will not be viable to rewrite this code for process 2. I have thought of ideas, please could you advise on which is the best solution and or give advice.

**Idea One**

Use Named pipes to communicate between processes and pass parameters and return values around.

**Idea Two**

Use Share Memory to share parameters and return values

**Idea Three**

Use windows messages, I honestly think this will not work

**Idea Four**

Somehow create a executable portion of shared memory and execute this code with a far jmp.

Please could you advise.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the size of process 2? You'probably just creating yourself a much bigger problem...

Comment: Idea 5 Put the code that process 2 needs into process 2.

Comment: The reason that I want to process two to be small is cus it is not my process, process 2 can be any process with my hooking DLL injected into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although putting the code in the process which needs to call it is good advice in general, in the particular case of a watchdog (also debugger and any other form of error handler) using separate processes is correct.  You don't want the watchdog to fail due to an error in the main code, so it needs to be a separate process.

A named pipe would be ideal in this scenario, the [`TransactNamedPipe` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365790%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is designed just for this.

Answer (score 2):

RPC was invented long ago. Then COM on top of that. In my opinion best forget your idea, but if you must, use COM.

By the way, to communicate between processes on the same Windows machine without COM, use mailslots.

Seems you forgot about them in you list.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

A DLL is the standard implementation of idea 4. It's loaded in both address spaces, but shared in physical RAM. You don't need special tricks; it works everywhere and Windows will deal with any security issues for you.

It's also portable to most other Operating Systems, although they're generally called something else, e.g. .so on Linux.

Comment: I don't want to use a dll because process 2 is not my process, it's hooked by dll, the dll must check if it must proceed with the hooked function, this requires quite a bit of code, this code needs to be run by watchdog cus it's got extra info needed by the verification process

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is some IPC. For a lightweight and easy solution, simply define an application specific message with WM_APP and have a mapping from the wParam/lParam for parameters. If you find you need more than 8 bytes, you could use WM_COPYDATA instead.